# java android textViews aleatorios

Tags: java, android, textview

Hola Estoy escribiendo esto en android studio y estoy atascado aqui:

Tengo los siguientes 3 arreglos

```
String [] palabras = {"papa","mama", "casa", "mapa", "masa"};
String [][] silabasCorrectas= {{"pa","pa"},{"ma","ma"},{"ca","sa"},{"ma","pa"},{"ma","sa"}};
String[] silabas = {"pa","ma","ca","sa"};
```

Y por otro lado tengo un arreglo más con 4 TextViews.

Luego genero un número aleatorio (llamado carta actual) para seleccionar una palabra aleatoria (del primer array declarado ahí arriba) y su correspondiente array de silabas correctas (segundo array).

He colocado cada silaba correcta de esa palabra aleatoria en uno de esos TextViews de manera aleatoria.
Asi:

```
  //para cada silaba correcta
    for (int silaba_i=0; silaba_i < silabasCorrectas[cartaActual].length; silaba_i++){

        //escoger un text view aleatorio
        tv_Aleatorio = (int)(Math.random()*textViewCount);

        //si ese textview aleatorio se encuentra vacío:
        if (textView[tv_Aleatorio].getText().toString().equals("")){

           //colocar la silaba correcta en el textView
           textView[tv_Aleatorio].setText(silabasCorrectas[cartaActual][silaba_i]);
        }
        else {
            //volver a hacer lo mismo con la misma silaba correcta
            silaba_i--;
        }

    }
```

Hasta ahí, el programa funciona bien.

Luego quiero completar los Textviews faltantes con silabas "incorrectas"

Estoy intentando de la siguiente manera:

```
//para cada TextView[t]
    for (int k =0; k< textViewCount; k++) {

        //si el TextView está vacío:
        if (textView[k].getText().toString().equals("")) {


            int silabaAleatoria = (int) (Math.random() * silabas.length);

            do {
                //para cada silabaCorrecta[silaba_i]:
                for (int silaba_i = 0; silaba_i < silabasCorrectas[cartaActual].length; silaba_i++) {

                    //si la silaba correcta[silaba_i] es igual a silaba aleatoria:
                    if (silabasCorrectas[cartaActual][silaba_i].equals(silabas[silabaAleatoria])) {
                        sonIguales = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (!sonIguales);

            //Una vez que ya comparó la sílaba aleatoria con todas las silabas correctas

            //Si NO SON IGUALES
            if (!sonIguales){
                //guardar silaba aleatoria en textView[k]
                textView[k].setText(silabas[silabaAleatoria]);

            } else { //Si la sílaba aleatoria es igual a alguna de las silabas correctas
                k--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Agregando esa parte, la app directamente no muestra nada de nada. Ni siquiera muestra la parte gráfica con los TextViews vacíos o con errores. 
¿Me podrían indicar el/los error/es que vean?

Lo único que conseguí hacer es rellenar los TextViews faltantes con sílabas aleatorias, pero se me desmadra cada vez que quiero comprobar si ésas sílabas aleatorias son correctas o no (yo quiero que no lo sean, porque a las correctas ya las coloqué).

Answer (score 0):

No estoy 100% seguro, pero me parece que la condición de salida del ciclo do..while va a ocasionar que la variable sonIguales salga del ciclo con el valor "true" siempre.
En ese caso, la línea

```
        textView[k].setText(silabas[silabaAleatoria]);
```

nunca se va a ejecutar

Comment: Hola @ChristopherRieder! Gracias por contestarme.

He probado quitando el "do while", y el problema persiste.

Comment: claro
posiblemente la lógica de los loops sea errónea.
que haría yo?
factoriza la lógica en una función para saber si una sílaba es correcta

vas a tener una funcion/metodo que va a ser public boolean isValidSyllable(string syllabe, string[] validSyllabe)
y ahí implementas la lógica esa.

también usa el for-each de java para mejor legibilidad, no estás usando los índices más que para acceder a los strings posicionados en tal índice.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta ponerlo de esta forma. Ya que como ya comprobaste que el texview esta vacío solo deberías iterar la silaba. Ese k-- del else es muy raro

```
//para cada TextView[t]
    for (int k =0; k< textViewCount; k++) {

        //si el TextView está vacío:
        if (textView[k].getText().toString().equals("")) {

            do {
            int silabaAleatoria = (int) (Math.random() * silabas.length);


                //para cada silabaCorrecta[silaba_i]:
                for (int silaba_i = 0; silaba_i < silabasCorrectas[cartaActual].length; silaba_i++) {

                    //si la silaba correcta[silaba_i] es igual a silaba aleatoria:
                    if (silabasCorrectas[cartaActual][silaba_i].equals(silabas[silabaAleatoria])) {
                        sonIguales = true;
                    }
                }


                //Una vez que ya comparó la sílaba aleatoria con todas las silabas correctas

               //Si NO SON IGUALES
               if (!sonIguales){
                   //guardar silaba aleatoria en textView[k]
                   textView[k].setText(silabas[silabaAleatoria]);

               } 
            }
            while (!sonIguales);
        }
    }
```